# Increase in memory consumption after updating Ubuntu to 18.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ram, memory-usage

Something very odd has been observed between Ubuntu 16.04LTS & 18.04LTS i.e memory consumption. Even during the startup memory consumption is more in 18.04LTS. Now when the PC start's it consumes 20% of 8GB memory for 18.04LTS which were 12-14% of 8GB memory in the case of 16.04LTS. After launching a few application like Firefox and Visual Studio Code memory consumption is more in present version(18.04LTS) compared to the previous version 16.04LTS though we all know it depends on the number of tabs opened still, would say consumption of memory has increased in case of 18.04LTS compared to the 16.04LTS will it stabilize in future updates?

Comment: In 16.04 which desktop environment you were using? In my opinion Unity(default in 16.04) is lighter than GNOME (default in 18.04). That could be reason. Also specify 20% and 12-14% in MBs since it could be helpful for answers.

Comment: Can you include the output from `free -h` in your question? We should not speculate if RAM consumption goes up, goes down or stays the same in future updates. To complement @N0rbert comment you can use the Unity desktop instead of Gnome desktop.

Comment: GNOME Shell in 18.04 LTS has memory leak. If you need to do your work consider to try MATE DE or Cinnamon.